# Simplifying Square Root: With a number and variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently doing a math problem, and was confused about whether I was allowed to further simplify $\sqrt x * \sqrt{35}$ into $\sqrt{35x} $

I have searched online and could not find any sources which stated it would be okay to do.

Comment: Yes, it is ok...

Comment: Square root is "a power"  not integer but fractional and you have the algebraic elementary formula $$a^m\cdot b^m=(ab)^m$$ You have just applied this.

Answer (score 0):

$$a^m \cdot b^m = (ab)^m$$

E.g.,

$$9^{1/2} \cdot 16^{1/2} = 3 \cdot 4 = (9 \cdot 16)^{1/2} = 144^{1/2} = 12$$

Comment: Would you mind using proper math formatting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify an expression under a radical by extracting perfect squares. For example, $\sqrt{24}=\sqrt{4\cdot6}=\sqrt{4}\cdot\sqrt{6}=2\cdot\sqrt{6}=2\sqrt{6}.$ What you are proposing is doing the opposite, i.e. turning $2\sqrt{6}$ into $\sqrt{24}$. Since one direction is allowed, what you are proposing is also perfectly "legal."